# -JSONValue failed Error trace

Tags: objective-c, json, cocoa, json-framework

how solve this excepetion

> -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
>       "Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=11 \"Unexpected end of string\" UserInfo=0x6173d50 {NSLocalizedDescription=Unexpected end of string}"

this is my code

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSString *str = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:buffer encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    NSArray *array = [str JSONValue];

    if (!array)
        return;

    NSDateFormatter *fmt = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [fmt setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in array) {
        NSLog(@"Class of eve_date = %@", [[dict objectForKey:@"eve_date"]class]);

        NSDate *d = [fmt dateFromString:[dict objectForKey:@"eve_date"]];

        NSLog(@"%@",d);
        [eventPHP addObject:[Events eventsNamed:[dict objectForKey:@"title_event"] description:[dict objectForKey:@"description"] date:d]];
    }
}
```

This is the data retrieve from server :

```
{"event":[{"eve_date":"2011-12-24","eve_time":"1 pm","title":"Tooth Regeneration Research","decription":"Tooth Regeneration Research:Where Do we stand today?\r\n\r\nBy: Dr.Tarek H El-Bialy,phD,FRCD(c)\r\n\r\nvenue:VIP ROOM,college of Dentistry,KSU"},{"eve_date":"2011-12-21","eve_time":"8 am","title":"The First Knowledge Translation(KT)","decription":"The First Knowledge Translation(KT)symposium in saudi Arabia\r\n\r\nvenue: main Auditorium,college of medicine\r\n\r\nFor Registration and further inquiries please concat:\r\n\r\nTel:4690790\/Email:ebhc-kt@ksu.edu.sa"}]}
```

Comment: You don't say which line throws the exception, but I suspect it's the `[str JSONValue]` call. A few suggestions:

1) You need to show how you construct the `buffer` variable. I suspect you're missing some data off the end of the buffer, so it stops in the middle of the string.
2) Or maybe the data isn't actually UTF8? (Though that is unlikely.) 
3) What is the string showing before the call to `-JSONValue`?

Answer (score 0):

The error means the JSON blob you asked it to deserialize is incomplete. In other words, you didn't hand it a well-formed blob of JSON. Either you got incomplete data back from the server, or you didn't store it properly as it came in.

Comment: I edite my question because i think my be problem in parsing format ?

Comment: @TahanieALsanie: Did you print that blob of JSON from your app, or is that what you're expecting the server to return? If it's the latter, try putting an `NSLog(@"JSON: %@", str);` line in your code before you call `-JSONValue`

Comment: ya i test it but doesn't print str this is result:
2011-12-20 04:16:34.600 iKSU[1851:207] JSON: 
2011-12-20 04:16:34.601 iKSU[1851:207] -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (

Comment: @TahanieALsanie: Looks like your string is completely empty. Try printing the data instead (`NSLog(@"JSON data: %@", buffer);`). It sounds like you never filled up your buffer with the data from the server. In fact, your buffer may very well be `nil`.